# window.__proto__ equivalent for IE10

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-10

I am wondering how to enumerate `window` functions like `setTimeout` or `alert` in IE10. In all other "modern" browsers (inluding IE11) I can get them with:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window.__proto__)
```

But in IE10 `window.__proto__` is not defined. As in all other browthers

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)
```

does contain many functions, but not all (including the two mentioned above).

How do I enumerate those in IE10?

Comment: What's bad with good old `for (var i in window) if (typeof window[i] === 'function' && !window.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(i);`? You can drop the `hasOwnProperty` check, of course, if that's not what you need. )

Comment: Have you tried `Object.getPrototypeOf(window)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get enumerable and non-enumerable properties of the `Window` object with:

```
var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(window))
```

the getPrototypeOf method is available in IE9+.